# Unable to run Sugar on Arch Linux due to PyGIWarning

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, python, x-server

### Installing Sugar environment on Arch

I just installed a fresh Arch Linux just to run [Sugar](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Welcome_to_the_Sugar_Labs_wiki) on it.

After downloading `sugar` from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/sugar/) using `yaourt -S sugar` I wanted to run Sugar using `sugar-runner` which was downloaded with `yaourt` as well.

Everything should be alright according to [the tutorial from wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sugar).

Note that I do everything from a terminal since I haven't got any graphical environment yet.

#### The logs

These are the logs I got after running `sugar-runner`:

```
/usr/bin/sugar-runner:28: PyGIWarning: SugarRunner was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('SugarRunner', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import SugarRunner

# The terminal wasn't printing for a few seconds here.

/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

#### I've tried to solve it ...

I thought I could solve it by providing an additional line to the `/usr/bin/sugar-runner` according [the solution from this website](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1259747).

I could not solve it this way however.

If I write

```
gi.require_version('SugarRunner', '1.0')
from gi.repository import SugarRunner
```

I get `NameError: name 'gi' is not defined`

and if I write

```
require_version('SugarRunner', '1.0')
from gi.repository import SugarRunner
```

I get `NameError: name 'require_version' is not defined`.

You can view the source code of `sugar-runner` on [this repo](https://github.com/sugarlabs/sugar-runner).

Additionally, I don't know what is happening to the `X server` and why `xinit` is *giving up*.

#### Running `sugar-runner` as a root

Because `Xorg.wrap` shouted at me that

> Only console users are allowed to run the X server

I decided to login as a root and then run `sugar-runner`. As a result I got this log messages:

```
/usr/bin/sugar-runner:28: PyGIWarning: SugarRunner was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('SugarRunner', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import SugarRunner


X.Org X Server 1.18.0
Release Date: 2015-11-09
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.2.3-1-ARCH i686 
Current Operating System: Linux haejzer 4.2.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 08:28:41 CET 2015 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=c296b0f7-dc8b-426d-9bc6-fc72db4c4673 rw quiet
Build Date: 18 November 2015  08:09:07AM

Current version of pixman: 0.32.8
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.99.log", Time: Sat Nov 28 20:01:34 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
/usr/libexec/sugar-runner/xinitrc:25: PyGIWarning: SugarRunner was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('SugarRunner', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import SugarRunner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/libexec/sugar-runner/xinitrc", line 81, in <module>
    _setup_xdg_user_dirs()
  File "/usr/libexec/sugar-runner/xinitrc", line 77, in _setup_xdg_user_dirs
    subprocess.check_call("xdg-user-dirs-update")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Here is a link to my `/var/log/Xorg.99.log` file: http://pastebin.com/E8uWNdi1.

#### After installing `xdg-user-dirs`

Thanks to [Wieland's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246133/128489) I've installed the `xdg-user-dirs` package.

Subsequently, the logs written by `sugar-runner` have changed:

```
/usr/libexec/sugar-runner/xinitrc:25: PyGIWarning: SugarRunner was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('SugarRunner', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import SugarRunner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/libexec/sugar-runner/xinitrc", line 89, in <module>
    os.kill(int(os.environ["GNOME_KEYRING_PID"]), signal.SIGTERM)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID'
xinit: connection to X server lost
```

The whole log file: http://pastebin.com/nU3scfYh
The video featuring the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdLMX0oUUTw

---

Have you got any idea how I can solve it?

*Or maybe you know how to deploy Sugar on Arch the easy way?*

Comment: You can find more about this problem in this thread: https://socialhelp.sugarlabs.org/t/getting-sugar-to-run-on-arch-linux/138.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugar tries to run `xdg-user-dirs-update`:

```
File "/usr/libexec/sugar-runner/xinitrc", line 77, in _setup_xdg_user_dirs
  subprocess.check_call("xdg-user-dirs-update")
```

which you don't have. Install the package `xdg-user-dirs` which includes it.

/edit: For your new error message you'll have to wait until the Sugar guys fix that, they already have an open [pull request](https://github.com/sugarlabs/sugar-runner/pull/2) for it.